# Compute sum of the elements in a chunk of a dask array

Tags: python, dask

I'd like to apply a function to each block and return a single element, for example, from a 10x10 matrix I'd like to sum each 2x2 block.

I've tried some combinations of what you see below but I always get an `IndexError`.

```
m = da.from_array(np.ones((10,10)), chunks=(2,2))
def compute_block_sum(block):
    return np.array([np.sum(block)])
m.map_blocks(compute_block_sum, chunks=(1,1)).compute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the default settings `map_blocks` assumes that the user-provided function returns a numpy array of the same number of dimensions as the input.  So you can get your example above to work by adding in a second empty dimension to your `compute_block_sum` function using numpy slicing with `None`.

```
In [1]: import dask.array as da
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: m = da.from_array(np.ones((10,10)), chunks=(2,2))

In [4]: def compute_block_sum(block):
   ...:     return np.array([np.sum(block)])[:, None]

In [5]: m.map_blocks(compute_block_sum, chunks=(1, 1)).compute()
Out[5]: 
array([[ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.]])
```